# How to store output in json variable and draw it on success?

Tags: php, json, opencart

I am using Opencart 2.0.2.0. Before that i was using Opencart 1.5.6.4. My code is as below,

```
       if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/onepagecheckout/address.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/onepagecheckout/address.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/onepagecheckout/address.tpl';
        }

        $json['hasshipping'] = $this->cart->hasShipping();  
        $json['output'] = $this->render();
        $this->response->setOutput($this->model_onepagecheckout_checkout->jsonencode($json));
```

This was working fine. I get it on checkout page and i render HTML by `json['output']`. But in `Opencart 2.0.2.0` i can not do the same.

> My code is as below

```
      $json['hasshipping'] = $this->cart->hasShipping();    

      $json['output'] = $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/onepagecheckout/address.tpl', $data));

}
      $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
      $this->response->setOutput($this->model_onepagecheckout_checkout->jsonencode($json));
```

I am getting it as an HTML in console. And i have also checked `dataType` is `JSON` in my ajax code. How can i solve it. Thanks!

**Edit**

> Here is the snap of response of version 1.5.6.4

[image]

> Here is the response image of version 2.0.2.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just need to remove $this->response->setOutput when load view to json result.
so the code will look like this :

```
$json['hasshipping'] = $this->cart->hasShipping();
$json['output'] = $this->load->view('default/template/onepagecheckout/address.tpl', $data);

$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

Comment: Maybe add some context to the question (a year is long for us coders ... ;-)